# vagrant command not running for magento setup

Tags: magento, installation, vagrant

How do I run a command in vagrant?
While using below commands for install magento setup:

```sh
vagrant@precise64:~/magento2$ sudo dnf install httpd
```

I get the following error:

```
sudo: dnf: command not found
```

So, how do I run a command in vagrant?

Comment: Have you installed dnf packages?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post code and errors as text in your question, not as images.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ***apt*** for package installation on precise 64 box.

You can do `sudo apt-get install apache2`

To configure it, you can use vim/nano to modify:

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

DNF Package manager is not available on *[hashicorp/Precise64](https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search)* as it's not .rpm based.

From [DNF WIKI](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/DNF?rd=Dnf):

> DNF is a software package manager that installs, updates, and removes
>   packages on RPM-based Linux distributions